# Github actions - variables

Tags: variables, github-actions, launch-template

I am new to GitHub action and I am trying to pull a variable from a file but I cannot get it to work. Could anyone help, please?

Also I want my default version always to be the latest. You can set that to update in terraform but I can't find the AWS CLI command

```
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: aws ec2 modify-launch-template --launch-template-id $LAUNCH-TEMPLATE-ID --default-version 3
        with:
          varFile: 'fr-stage-variables.json'
```

Comment: Are you getting any error and can you add it to your question?

Comment: It seems that what you want is to convert variables from a JSON to a ENV variable inside your workflow. If this is what you want to achieve, I would suggest using this [action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/convert-json-to-env). Let me know if you have any question regarding how to do it after reading the uses cases on the repo.